# Keybord doesn't work on 16.04 Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, dell, logitech, logitech-unifying

Recently my laptop keyboard stopped working. I'm now using Logitech wireless keyboard and configured it with a receiver via **Solaar**.

My laptop Keyboard was working before, I actually have no idea why it stopped working.

Kindly give some suggestion or solutions regarding this problem.

**EDIT**: Wireless Logitech keyboard and mouse are working just fine, but my laptop keyboard is not responding. When I type on it, keys got lighten up so it recognize the action but it has 0 effect in GUI.

**EDIT2**: I tried to reinstall my system now, wirelss keyboard is working from very beginning while notebook keyboard is not working - Solaar is not installed

**EDIT3: Grub file:**

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=9d551829-77be-4690-8097-0bd9b6adce29  acpi=force acpi_osi=! ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Comment: Does it work in other computers?

Comment: Normal wireless keyboard is working just fine, i'm speaking about laptop keyboard only

Comment: Does the laptop keyboard work in BIOS?

Comment: Yes it is working . I just tried to reinstall my system. Wireless mouse and keyboard is working from very beginning even without solaar while default laptop keyboard is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motherboard was damaged. After replacement everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with my ASUS GL552VW. Fixed with a simple kernel parameter change.

1) Install **Grub Customizer**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

2) Open Grub Customizer and Edit the grub entry (with the Pencil Icon) 
[image: Grub Customizer]

3) Now make the desired changes. In this case,[image: Edit Menu]

you need to add a parameter on the second last line that starts with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-xxx....` add `acpi_osi=!` before `ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`

You might also want to use `acpi=force`

Click OK and Save. Now hard reset your laptop. It should be fixed from the next boot.

I'm using these parameters to boot and this fixes all the function keys operations, keyboard backlight, graphics and the shutdown problem.

`linux  /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=7e43add9-fbc2-4946-a640-0b269d17c117 i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=1 nvidia.modeset=1 idle=nomwait acpi=force acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=native ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`

Comment: please explain how to set a boot parameter, OP may not know this

Comment: edited. 
Link added http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7662/6199

Comment: the link may break so please include steps here

Comment: OK. added everything

Comment: wow... I would just edit `/etc/default/grub` but thanks for improving your answer :)

Comment: wow, thank you for very detailed answer. Unfortunately it did not work for me.  After replaceing keybord with a new dell one  only 3 buttons worked .  Keybord lightup  control and screen brightness controll. 

I post my GRUB in description

Toommorow i'll try with motherbord exchange

Comment: Okey, replacement of motherboard do the trick.  Thank you all for help.